# T4MVC and parameter with list not creating correct url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Is there a way to generate a url with T4MVC with a parameter of list?  Right now it gives me this.

```
  public virtual ActionResult Scoresheets(int? eventId, int? gameId, List<int> gameIds)
        {

Url.ActionAbsolute(MVC.EventReports.Scoresheets(eventId, gameId, gameIds))


http://localhost:2222/24086/event/documents/scoresheets?gameids=system.collections.generic.list%601%5bsystem.int32%5d
```

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you expecting here? e.g. a comma separated list of id's?

One option may be to write a Model Unbinder, as described in section 3.1 of the [doc](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: Well since ASP.NET MVC can only handle ?gameIds=1001&gameIds=1005 I guess that would be it.

Comment: I thought about returning an anonymous type with a method on that object, in this case an extension method for a list for T4MVC and pass it as an anonymous type, kind of like this http://bntr.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/asp-mvc-passing-an-object-to-an-action-using-t4mvc-strongly-typed-actions/

Comment: Did you try using a Model Unbinder? I would think it could handle this.